# Heroku cant find my index.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack

I get this error in heroku `GET https://my-app.herokuapp.com/index.js 404 (Not Found)`

my Procfile has this in it: `web: npm start`

Then in my package.json I have `"start": "node ./app/index.js"`

my app folder at root level contains an `index.js` that contains:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

and my `webpack.config.js` file contains:

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
 entry: './main.js',

 output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
   filename: 'index.js'
 },

 module: {
   loaders: [
     {
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       loader: 'babel',
       query: {
         presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
       }
     },
     {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
   ]
 }
}
```

Perhaps I need to point it at my `public/index.js` file but when I did this it still didn't recognise it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a misunderstanding of how node and or servers in general work. You should be able to go to `GET https://my-app.herokuapp.com/` and it will return to you the `index.html` file that resides in your public folder. Telling node to start with `"start": "node ./app/index.js"` simply means run this file to start the server. The server than listens on the routes you define with:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

This is listening on the path `https://my-app.herokuapp.com/`

If you wanted to listen to `https://my-app.herokuapp.com/anotherroute`, you would change the prior to:

```
app.get('/anotherroute', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

And since you used `app.use('/', express.static('public'));` any files that match your route will be served automatically. Meaning if you have a file in your `public` directory like `apple.jpg`, you can retrieve it with `https://my-app.herokuapp.com/apple.jpg`